# Reference MVC 5.2.3 in VS2015 without local packages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, publish

I am trying to minimize publish footprint of projects.  I am looking at hundreds of sites and I don't want to publish the same DLLs hundreds of times if I can prevent it.

I need to target  4.6.1 framework and MVC 5.2.3 but VS2015 insists on including them in the packages and bin folder.

Anyone have tips on referencing these and not having them publish to the server with every website?  I need the project to run locally and be published to IIS.

Comment: " hundreds of times " you mean on the same machine or to hundreds of machines?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to?  If you installed it in the GAC then all of your websites would have to use the exact same version.

Comment: One (actually a pair of load balanced servers) server, hundreds of websites on it.

Comment: The server(s) has almost 1100 sites.  More than 600 are running the CMS I am migrating to MVC5 from MVC3

Comment: From what I've seen there's no push to have an installer that would put MVC in the GAC.  You could _try_ manually installing the assemblies in the GAC on the server but you would probably need to to that locally as well to keep the assemblies from getting deployed to IIS.

Comment: Just seems insane to publish 1.25mb of DLLs 600-1000 times on a single server.  With MVC3 we didn't have to do that.  Now with MVC5 we do?  I know HD space is cheap but this bloat seems out of control.  It will clog up the RAID.  It will fill up the backups.  For no real reason I can see.